# When I pass the variable(path) in azure devops server shell script task, path prints without "/"

Tags: linux, shell, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I am using the Azure DevOps server pipeline shell script task when I passed the "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" variable as a shell script arguments, I found the path is not getting "/" while printing the variable.

**Here is the Azure DevOps Pipeline Task:**
[image]

**Here is my shell script:**

> !/bin/bash
>     echo $1

**Here is the output of the pipeline:**

[image]

please give some idea how I can get actual path (with "/") while printing the variable?

Comment: Use double quotes on the path like `"D:\Agent_1..."`.

Comment: Now getting like this "D:\Agent_1\work\s", missing " \1" in the path.

Comment: Update command as `sh tfsvariable.sh "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"` in the task configuration and try.

Comment: Updated Command as: sh tfsvariable.sh "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
 Getting Like this: "D:\Agent_1\work^A\s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I have added Azure DevOps Server 2019 predefine variable as extra vars in azure-pipelines.yml like this:

```
- task: Ansible@0
  inputs:
    ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
    playbookPathOnAgentMachine: 'ansible/tfs_playbooks/install_agent.yml'
    inventoriesAgentMachine: 'file'
    inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: 'hosts.yml'
    args: '--extra-vars "build_source_dir=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"'
```

Then I can access the variable in my playbook using this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: show debug
    debug:
      msg: "Dir {{ build_source_dir }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I am not guess wrong, the agent this pipeline is using located in Windows?*

---

Please try with the pass the variable as `$BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` without any double or single quote(s).

[image]

Comment: Hey, @Merlin I have applied **$BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY** variable. This time output is blank " ", not able to see anything.

Comment: @DhartiSutariya,Does the system you agent located is windows?

Comment: Yes, Agent is running on windows and added one  **SSH service connection** of Linux server in Azure DevOps Server 2019